# Page object model not extending driver from class

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, pageobjects

**Base Class :**

```
protected WebDriver driver;
protected String URL = "https://www.example.com/";
public static String SignupURL = "https://www.example.com/login";
public Login loginpage;

@BeforeClass
public void setup()
{

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\Selenium-Webdriver\\Chrome_Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.navigate().to(URL);
    loginpage = PageFactory.initElements(driver,Login.class);

}
```

**Login Class :**

```
protected WebDriver driver;

public Login(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;}

public Login Method1()
{

    //Logic

}
```

**LoginTest Class :**

```
  public class LoginTest extends Base {

  @Test
 public void method1()
 {
        setup() //Have to Call it
       //Logic

  }

 @Test 
 public void method2
 {   
     setup() //Have to Call it 
     //Logic
  }
```

}

Question is Why it require to call **setup()** method for every method in test class.

I am already extending class then driver should call automatically but it's not. When I do not call **setup()** then getting **Nullpointer Exception**, If I call it then system opening new browser for each and every method.

Comment: can you please paste the complete error message you are getting. I think this is because the script is not able to identify the driver.

Comment: At first look code looks like OK, You don't need to call setup in each method, can you share your trace log may be it is generate nullpointer some other piece of code,

Comment: Use @BeforeTest annotation and make the webdriver public...it works for me...... i think this will also help u

Comment: @noor - I tried that but seems not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using @BeforeClass in Base class, if change it to @BeforeSuite then no need to call that setup method. Generally i will use @BeforeSuite in mybase class and extend it to all test classes to work on that browser.

below one worked for me

```
 import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
 import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;

 public class Base {


protected WebDriver driver;
protected String URL = "https://www.google.com/";
public static String SignupURL = "https://www.google.com/";
//public Login loginpage;

@BeforeSuite
public void setup()
{

  //  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\Selenium-Webdriver\\Chrome_Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.navigate().to(URL);
   // loginpage = PageFactory.initElements(driver,Login.class);

}


}


import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestCasePage1 extends Base{

@Test
public void testit(){
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
}

@Test
public void testit1(){
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
}

}
```

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: Thanks but I am getting **java.lang.NullPointerException** when use @BeforeSuite.

Comment: can you please try once by changing protected WebDriver driver; to public static WebDriver driver; once

Comment: updated answers.. looks like u r getting null because of logic in that method1 may be u r calling from LoginPage where driver is null

Comment: I can not comments lines which you did because each method of my login page returns object of Login data type :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111507/discussion-between-helping-hands-and-murali-seleniumtrainer).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `@BeforeClass` misses `(alwaysRun=true)`. So if, in your base class, you write `@BeforeClass(alwaysRun=true)`. Then you don't need to call setup in the other classes.